# Shopify Worldwide shop and solution - need advice

Tags: internationalization, shopify, e-commerce, shopify-app

I am trying to establish a worldwide shopify shop solution and feel a bit left alone in shopify due to lack of international apps or options. I have already Zonos for duties and taxes but are there any other options or ideas how to be more international and do you know of any other solution for duties and taxes as well?  Appreciate your feedback and suggestions on this.